# ListView keeps empty when i bind same property to another ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, binding

If i bind the same property to another control of same type, in my case to a ListView then the first ListView will be filled with object but the second ListView keep empty. i played arround with OneWay and TwoWay mode but until now i cant find a solution to show same entries  in both ListViews.
[image]

Here is my Code.
I hope you can help me.
p.s. I use MVVM

**App.Xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WPF_TestApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainView.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#FF313131" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,5,5" Margin="5,0,5,5">
            <ListView
              AlternationCount="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#FF313131" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,5,5" Margin="5,0,5,5">
            <ListView 
              AlternationCount="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using WPF_TestApp.MVVM.ViewModel;

namespace WPF_TestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainViewModel viewModel {  get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            viewModel = new MainViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Windows.Controls;

using WPF_TestApp.MVVM.Model;

namespace WPF_TestApp.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainModel Model { get; set; }
        public BindableCollection<ListViewItem> Items { get; set; }


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Model = new MainModel();
            Items = Model.Items;
        }

    }
}
```

**MainModel.cs**

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WPF_TestApp.MVVM.Model
{
    public class MainModel
    {
        public BindableCollection<ListViewItem> Items {  get; set; }
        public MainModel()
        {
            Items = new BindableCollection<ListViewItem>();

            for(int i = 0; i<=100; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.Content = $"Item >>>{i.ToString()}";
                Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add ListViewItems manually to the `Items` collection. A `ListViewItem` is a UI element that can only have a single parent element in the visual tree. It can not be contained in two visual trees, i.e. two ListViews at the same time.

Instead of `BindableCollection<ListViewItem>`, use `BindableCollection<string>`. A ListViewItem will automatically be created for each string item in the ListView.

```
public class MainModel
{
    public BindableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new BindableCollection<string>();

    public MainModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Items.Add($"Item >>>{i}");
        }
    }
}
```

---

As a note, you would not use a `ListView` when you are not setting its `View` property, e.g. to a `GridView`. Use the simpler `ListBox` base class instead.

Comment: Perfect! Works fine thank you. I did not know that.

Comment: In my real application i set the view property. in this Example i only want to explain my problem as near as possible. What about if i use BindableCollection<object>? In my real application i use this to fill another ListView, but i got the same result as above although i dont create ListViewItems manually.  I use BindableCollection<object> direct in Binding property.

Comment: You could use `BindableCollection<object>` and add strings to the collection as shown in the answer. If you add ListViewItems, it won't work for the same reason as explained in the answer.

Comment: Sorry forgot to explain... the objects in the BindableCollection<object> are custom created ComboBoxes. So i got a ListView with ComboBoxes in it. Therfor i use <object>. I'm sure there is a better solution but in my case i did it like this. And as i said i got the same behavior. Is this the right or expected behavior and only <string> works as you explained in your answer?

Comment: The explanation is the same. ComboBoxes are also UI elements. The item should be a *data item*, i.e. an instance of a class the holds the data to populate a ComboBox. The actual ComboBox should be declared in the ItemTemplate of a ListBox or a CellTemplate of a GridViewColumn. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me a lot. you saved my evening.